# Update the same table in the trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table which calculate the total deduction and the remaining deduction from the previous month.

And any update in the remaining deduction of old month should affect the next months in order, so I've created an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for this table, but I've noticed that the trigger is not invoked by the `UPDATE` for the next month.

Check the trigger code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgUpdateRemainingBalance]
ON [dbo].[GAT_MONTHLY_DEDUCTION] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @OldTotalDeduction INT 
DECLARE @NewTotalDeduction INT
DECLARE @OldRemainingToNextMonth INT
DECLARE @NewRemainingToNextMonth INT

SELECT @OldRemainingToNextMonth = RemainingToNextMonth,
@OldTotalDeduction = TotalDeduction
FROM DELETED

SELECT @NewRemainingToNextMonth = RemainingToNextMonth,
@NewTotalDeduction = TotalDeduction
FROM INSERTED

DECLARE @EmpNo BIGINT
DECLARE @RegDate DATETIME

SELECT @EmpNo = PersonnelNo, @RegDate = RegDate FROM INSERTED

IF (@OldRemainingToNextMonth <> @NewRemainingToNextMonth) OR (@OldTotalDeduction <> @NewTotalDeduction)
BEGIN
UPDATE GAT_MONTHLY_DEDUCTION
SET TotalDeduction = TotalDeduction - @OldRemainingToNextMonth + @NewRemainingToNextMonth,
Visited = 1
WHERE RegDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @RegDate) AND PersonnelNo = @EmpNo
END
END
```

I am doing updating for the same table which has this triggers but calling the trigger for the first time should call the trigger again for the next update but it is not happening.

It is urgent for me to know how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish? It looks like you're wanting to update TotalDeduction for all months after the month that has been changed, but the trigger can not be triggered from within the trigger. I ask, because the way it's written now would only update the next month, even if trigger was called for subsequent updates: The only fields changed are TotalDeduction and Visited, and since RemainingToNextMonth has not changed, there would be no changes in subsequent updates except for the visited flag.

Answer (score 9):

One thing to watch out for: the SQL Server trigger is fired **once per statement** (and **NOT** once per row as many developer think/assume)

If that statement updates more than one row, then the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain **multiple rows** - so your selects like

```
SELECT 
    @NewRemainingToNextMonth = RemainingToNextMonth,
    @NewTotalDeduction = TotalDeduction
FROM INSERTED
```

**will fail** - which row should be selected, if there are fifty of them in `Inserted`??

You will need to rewrite your trigger to be able to deal with multiple rows being handled at once, in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables...